# Python: Search a string for a variable repeating characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a function that will search a string (all numeric, 0-9) for a variable sequence of 4 or more repeating characters.

Here are some example inputs:

"14888838": the function would return True because it found "8888".

"1111":     the function would return True because it found "1111".

"1359":     the function would return False because it didn't find 4 repeating characters in a row.

My first inclination is to use re, so I thought the pattern :"[0-9]{4}" would work but that returns true as long as it finds any four numerics in a row, regardless of whether they are matching or not.

Anyway, thanks in advance for your help.

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may rely on [**capturing**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
if re.search(r'(\d)\1{3}', s):
    print(s)
```

Here, `(\d)` captures a digit into Group 1 and `\1{3}` matches 3 occurrences of the value captured that are immediately to the right of that digit.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP1gJ2/1) and a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Px7fvH)

```
import re
values = ["14888838", "1111", "1359"]
for s in values:
    if re.search(r'(\d)\1{3}', s):
        print(s)
```

Output:

```
14888838
1111
```

Comment: Agree, but you should avoid `input` because it's a builtin function in Python 3.